# SCCM - Application Client Installation Failure

Tags: sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

I have a problem which as only recently started post no changes.

SCCM clients are no longer picking up deployed applications. Please note this occured suddenly and i have tried the following steps;

- restarted the SCCM SQL Instance
- Restarted the SCCM server
- Checked the MPMSI log which i reporting

*Call to HttpSendRequestSync succeeded for port 80 with status code 200, text: OK
CMPControlManager::PublishInDNS: DnsReplaceRecordsInSet() failed with status 9005.*

- checked server side for the ccm logs
- checked client side for the execmgr.log & AppIntentEval.log

I still cant deduct a reason for this behavior. All was working as expected and post a large amount of SCCM client builds (96) newly imaged clients simply do not pick up the deployed software despite registering within SCCM.

Can someone please advise?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ClientLocation.log & LocationServices.log on the clients to see if any errors are reported in there. Also have you checked with your Infrastructure & Network people to make sure that there have been no changes to AD Sites & Services or IP Range changes which could affect your Boundaries.